# How to set a custom icon in a traits UI window

Tags: python, python-3.x, traitsui

I'm trying to use a custom icon in the titlebar (and taskbar if possible) of a GUI made in Traits UI, however I cannot find any information on how to do so. There is an `icon` attribute in the Traits UI View class, but I can't get it to change anything:
http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/custom_view.html#index-15

Google suggests there may be a convoluted solution involving directly interacting with pyqt4 but I wanted to check there wasn't a simpler solution first.

The gui is intended to run on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use the pyface `ImageResource` class. See:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from pyface.image_resource import ImageResource

class Person(HasTraits):
    first_name = Str
    last_name = Str

    view = View(Item('first_name'),
             Item('last_name'),
             icon=ImageResource('image_path.png'))

Person().configure_traits()
```

Comment: 1 more detail: the file is expected to be (and searched for) inside a folder called "images/" located next to the module containing the view code.